# How to build a responsive ListView using ConstraintLayout or RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to create a list view to display two TextViews and an ImageView right of the TextViews. I have tried designing this using Relative Layout only, RelativeLayout with nested LinearLayout and ConstraintLayout. All seem to work, but not responsively enough to fit different screens. For example it displays well on mobile, but not good enough on Android TV emulator.
I am at odds how to modify the following layout to show image on the right and the two TextViews on the left and try to fit the screen, but have the images align to each other.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_video_title"
        android:layout_width="179dp"
        android:layout_height="117dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_video_descr"
        android:layout_width="184dp"
        android:layout_height="239dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_video_title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_video_title"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.044" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_video_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="163dp"
        android:layout_height="381dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_video_descr"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_video_descr"
        android:contentDescription="@string/video_thumbnail_image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/video" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: For tv you should always create a separate layout

Comment: what `view` want to display

Comment: @VishalYadav this is used as a ListView item in my ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

## Try this

- According to you it display like this

---

[image: Layout Editor]

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_video_title"
        android:layout_width="179dp"
        android:layout_height="117dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_video_thumbnail"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_video_descr"
        android:layout_width="184dp"
        android:layout_height="239dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_video_title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_video_title"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.044"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_video_thumbnail"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_video_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="163dp"
        android:layout_height="381dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tv_video_descr"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_video_descr"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_video_descr"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.047" />
    
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You should use Ctrl+K to properly format source code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated xml file implement this I used a linear layout and assign layout weights so it cover all screen sizes depending on available width

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tv_video_title"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_video_descr"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_video_title"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_video_title"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.044" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_video_thumbnail"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_video_descr"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_video_descr"
            android:contentDescription="@string/video_thumbnail_image"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/video" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It will work mate let me know if you face some issues also not forget to mark my post as answer if it works for you :)

Comment: LinearLayout inside ConstraintLayout? The main goal of using ConstraintLayout is to flatten your layout and avoid of using nested layouts [Understanding the performance benefits of ConstraintLayout](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html)

Comment: If you want to use weight in ConstraintLayout you have to consider using weighted "spread" or "spread_inside" chains [Control linear groups with a chain](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constrain-chain).